# Queue 2013 TFS Team Build and specify GIT Key

Tags: xml, git, powershell, tfs, tfsbuild

I want to invoke a Team Build using Powershell.  I want to override the default MSBuild Arguments and specify the GIT Change Key.  I can't believe how difficult this is.

Specifying MSBuild parameters were hard enough because it was Json inside XML.

The following works on my local laptop but not on my TeamCity Build Server.

```
$buildserver = $tfs.GetService([Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client.IBuildServer])
$definition = $buildserver.GetBuildDefinition($teamProject, $buildDefinition)

# Deserialize ProcessParameters from the definition
$ProcessParameters = [Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.WorkflowHelpers]::DeserializeProcessParameters($definition.ProcessParameters)

$AdvancedBuildSettings = $ProcessParameters['AdvancedBuildSettings'].json | ConvertFrom-Json
$AdvancedBuildSettings.MSBuildArguments = "/p:one=parm1 /p:two='parm2'"
$ProcessParameters['AdvancedBuildSettings'].json = $AdvancedBuildSettings | ConvertTo-Json

$request = $definition.CreateBuildRequest()
$request.ProcessParameters = [Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.WorkflowHelpers]::SerializeProcessParameters($ProcessParameters)
$QueuedBuild = $buildserver.QueueBuild($request)
```

However I couldn't figure out what I needed to install to get the Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.dll installed so I punted on using the Deserialize Serialize helper calls and just did it myself.

However, getting access to the CheckoutOverrides setting is even worse.  The only way I could get it was to stub out a value in the definition because it isn't in the XML.  Once I stubbed it out the XML was fairly nasty with arrays based on type.  Here's a sample:

```
<Dictionary x:TypeArguments="x:String, x:Object" xmlns="clr-namespace:System.Collections.Generic;assembly=mscorlib" xmlns:mtbc="clr-namespace:Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Common;assembly=Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Common" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <x:Array x:Key="ProjectsToBuild" Type="x:String">
        <x:String>\TeamCityToTeamBuild\PullTeamCityBuild.proj</x:String>
    </x:Array>
    <x:Boolean x:Key="CleanRepository">False</x:Boolean>
    <mtbc:BuildParameter x:Key="AdvancedBuildSettings">
        {
        "MSBuildArguments":  " /p:TeamCityProjectId=\u0027%teamcity.project.id%\u0027 /p:TeamCityBuildNumber=%build.number% /p:TeamCityBuildOutput=\u0027\\\\scs40vptmcapp04.medassets.com\\D$\\work\\1f7b2c812110928e\u0027",
        "MSBuildPlatform":  "Auto",
        "PreActionScriptPath":  "",
        "PreActionScriptArguments":  "",
        "PostActionScriptPath":  "",
        "PostActionScriptArguments":  "",
        "RunCodeAnalysis":  "AsConfigured"
        }
    </mtbc:BuildParameter>
    <mtbc:BuildParameter x:Key="AgentSettings">{"MaxExecutionTime":"00:00:00","MaxWaitTime":"04:00:00","Name":"*","Tags":[],"TagComparison":"MatchAtLeast"}</mtbc:BuildParameter>
    <x:String x:Key="CheckoutOverride">SetIt</x:String>
</Dictionary>
```

Because this is a String it was a key under a String Element.  Using XPath with the namespace on the doc, this code looks like:

```
$ProcessParametersDoc = [xml]$definition.ProcessParameters
$ns = New-Object System.Xml.XmlNamespaceManager($ProcessParametersDoc.NameTable) 
$ns.AddNamespace('x',"http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml") 
$CheckoutOverridesNode = $ProcessParametersDoc.SelectSingleNode("//x:String[@x:Key='CheckoutOverride']",$ns)
$CheckoutOverridesNode.InnerText = $VersionControlNumber
```

Making it where it will flexibly create the String array if it doesn't exist will be yet another level of ridiculous.

The following code works (still have to add code to handle missing String node for CheckoutOverride) but it's like pulling hens teeth with pliers.

```
$tfs = [Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TeamFoundationServerFactory]::GetServer($serverName)

$buildserver = $tfs.GetService([Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client.IBuildServer])
$definition = $buildserver.GetBuildDefinition($teamProject, $buildDefinition)

$ProcessParametersDoc = [xml]$definition.ProcessParameters

$AdvancedBuildSettingsNode = $ProcessParametersDoc.Dictionary.BuildParameter | ?{$_.Key -eq 'AdvancedBuildSettings'}

$AdvancedBuildSettings = $AdvancedBuildSettingsNode.InnerXml | ConvertFrom-Json

$MsBuildArgs  = " /p:Arg1='Arg1Value'"
$MsBuildArgs += " /p:Arg2='Arg2Value'"
$AdvancedBuildSettings.MSBuildArguments = $MsBuildArgs

$AdvancedBuildSettingsNode.InnerXml = $AdvancedBuildSettings | ConvertTo-Json

$CheckoutOverridesNode = $ProcessParametersDoc.Dictionary.BuildParameter | ?{$_.Key -eq 'CheckoutOverrides'}

$ns = New-Object System.Xml.XmlNamespaceManager($ProcessParametersDoc.NameTable) 
$ns.AddNamespace('x',"http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml") 
$CheckoutOverridesNode = $ProcessParametersDoc.SelectSingleNode("//x:String[@x:Key='CheckoutOverride']",$ns)
$CheckoutOverridesNode.InnerText = $VersionControlNumber

$request = $definition.CreateBuildRequest()
$request.ProcessParameters = $ProcessParametersDoc.OuterXml

$QueuedBuild = $buildserver.QueueBuild($request)
```

I removed some of the code to handle the situation of missing XML nodes to make it more readable.  Even so, is this stable?  Is there a better way?  I'm just worried that even after I stabilize the code it could break with the next version of TFS.

Comment: Don't worry about the next version of TFS too much... TFS2015 will have an entirely new build system. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2015/02/12/build-futures.aspx

Comment: Dumb question... what do you mean by "Git change key"? I'm not sure what you're actually trying to do? Also, why not just use the TFSBuild command line utility. Why use powershell?

Comment: Thanks Daniel and Richard.  I know about the new Build Engine and I hope it helps things out.  This whole thread comes from my desire to do Builds in TeamCity but to feed that output into Team Build so I get my metrics, Builds for Bugs and Release.  Probably not too much danger they will break the current stuff if they limit it to legacy support.

Comment: As for the TFSBuild command, I suppose I can do that.  I loath installing Visual Studio on my TeamCity builds or hack it to invoke TFSBuild without an install.  Also, from what I see I don't get the ability to Queue and wait for the results from a build.  Even if I could then I'm parsing the output stream.  This isn't the way I do my Automation unless I'm forced to by evil overlords.

Comment: Your build stem should mirror your development platform. Do your developers have visual studio installed? Then your build servers should.

Comment: I  don't put Visual Studio on my Build Servers.  It works great - for building software.  Done it for years and it works.  Kind of crazy to install it, not for building my projects, but to simply invoke Team Build.

As I stated, I got by that anyway.  I'm still faced with a process of XML doc authoring with a strange schema.  Your suggestion doesn't help with that.